# Gradient of $\psi\left(\frac{u^T v}{\left\|u\right\|\left\|v\right\|}\right)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I have that $k(u,v) = \psi\left(\frac{u^T v}{\left\|u\right\|\left\|v\right\|}\right)$ where $u,v \in \mathbf{R}^{d}$ and I am interested in understanding why is $\nabla_u k(u,v) = \psi’\left(\frac{u^T v}{\left\|u\right\|\left\|v\right\|}\right)\left(v - \left(u^T v\right) u\right)$ how can I obtain this result? Also if I suppose that $\left\|u\right\|=\left\|v\right\|=1$ is the above still valid?

Comment: Use the chain rule

Comment: What is the gradient of $frac{1}{||u||}$ though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$\partial_u \left(\frac1{\left\|u\right\|}\right) = \partial_u \left(\left(u^Tu\right)^{-\frac12}\right) = -\frac12\left(u^T u\right)^{-\frac32}\partial_u \left(u^Tu\right) = -\frac12\left(u^T u\right)^{-\frac32}\times 2 u = -\frac{u}{\left\|u\right\|^{3}}$$ By using the chain rule:

$$\partial_u k(u,v) = \psi'\left(\frac{u^Tv}{\left\|u\right\|\left\|v\right\|}\right) \partial_u\left(\frac{u^Tv}{\left\|u\right\|\left\|v\right\|}\right) = \psi'\left(\frac{u^Tv}{\left\|u\right\|\left\|v\right\|}\right) \left(v\left\|u\right\|^2 - \left(u^Tv\right)u\right){\color{red}{\frac{1}{\left\|u\right\|^3\left\|v\right\|}}}.$$